# How to turn this static init into a dynamic one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this fancybox plugin wich is great, but I don't think there is enough examples on the [documentation](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('nav.main a#gallery').live('click',function() {
        $.fancybox([
            {href : 'img/galeria/fondo1.jpg', title : 'Title1','nextEffect' : 'fade',   'prevEffect'    : 'fade'}, 
            {href : 'img/galeria/fondo2.jpg', title : 'Title2','nextEffect' : 'fade',   'prevEffect'    : 'fade'},
            {href : 'img/galeria/fondo3.jpg', title : 'Title3','nextEffect' : 'fade',   'prevEffect'    : 'fade'}, 
            {href : 'img/galeria/fondo4.jpg', title : 'Title4','nextEffect' : 'fade',   'prevEffect'    : 'fade'}  
        ]);
    });
});
```

Well as you can see this loads a few images in the fancybox.

I would like to be able to do it by passing a javascript object to it so I don't need to know which, or how many images there are (in the init) and manage that updating the object, but I just don't see how to do this.

Can anyone help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to pass a valid json object?

```
function getGaleriaObject()
{
  // do your database / what ever stuff here
  var obj = [
            {href : 'img/galeria/fondo1.jpg', title : 'Title1','nextEffect' : 'fade',   'prevEffect'    : 'fade'}, 
            {href : 'img/galeria/fondo2.jpg', title : 'Title2','nextEffect' : 'fade',   'prevEffect'    : 'fade'},
            {href : 'img/galeria/fondo3.jpg', title : 'Title3','nextEffect' : 'fade',   'prevEffect'    : 'fade'}, 
            {href : 'img/galeria/fondo4.jpg', title : 'Title4','nextEffect' : 'fade',   'prevEffect'    : 'fade'}  
        ];
   return obj;
}

$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('nav.main a#gallery').live('click',function() {
      var obj = getGaleriaObject();    
      $.fancybox(obj);
    });
});
```

Examle: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kDZ6j/)

Comment: You don't need the eval in that. And you should probably demonstrate how to actually use that in his init function.

Comment: @Chris Thank you for the hint. I updated my answer to make it more clear

Comment: Cool. A much better answer now. :) +1